# Create a seaborn histogram with two columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I try to display a histogram with this dataframe.

```
   gr_age  weighted_cost
0       1    2272.985462
1       2    2027.919360
2       3    1417.617779
3       4     946.568598
4       5     715.731002
5       6     641.716770
```

I want to use `gr_age` column as the X axis and `weighted_cost` as the Y axis. Here is an example of what I am looking for with Excel:

[image: Histogram example]

I tried with the following code, and with `discrete=True`, but it gives another result, and I didn't do better with displot.

```
sns.histplot(data=df, x="gr_age", y="weighted_cost")
plt.show()
```

Thanking you for your ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a `barplot` (x vs y values) not a `histplot` which plots the distribution of a dataset:

```
import seaborn as sns
ax = sns.barplot(data=df, x='gr_age', y='weighted_cost', color='#4473C5')
ax.set_title('Values by age group')
```

output:

[image: seaborn barplot]